# React SSR with React Router runing on Deno

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom, deno

I'm trying to make a website with React SSR and React Router on Deno.

I've tried some examples and articles but I haven't been able to accomplish it.

The React part works but importing React Router gives errors:

- https://esm.sh: error: `Import 'https://cdn.esm.sh/v58/@babel/runtime@7.16.5/deno/helpers/esm/extends.js' failed: 500 Internal Server Error`
- https://dev.jspm.io: Doesn't give any error immediately but does when accessing its properties:

  - `error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'BrowserRouter' does not exist on type '{}'.`
  - Or:

    `1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app` (I specified the version to be the same on the URL)
- https://skypack.dev: The same as above.

How can I do this? (Where to import code, any articles to read, general steps to follow)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), showing us what you tried, and what errors occurred? Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a place for asking general advice, but if you can focus on a specific problem, then perhaps we can try to help you solve it.

Comment: @jsejcksn Edited the question to include the errors it gave me.